# Is there anyway to apply javascript to one input field?

Tags: javascript, function, time, field

This is a snippet of the code. I have a javascript function that produces a clock on click so that the customer can click a specific time for booking. The problem is due to the 'input' it goes across all fields of the form.

I want to be able to apply this function just to this field. Is that possible? I've been looking everywhere. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="field_holder">
    <label for='time'>Time: </label>
    <br />

    <input type="text" onFocus="$('input').timepicker();;" value="13:23" class="form-control">
</div>
```

Comment: Add an id to the element and then use id to apply timepicker on it

Comment: See that's one thing I did try. Getelementbyid.. Didn't seem to work though.

Comment: `$('#myBeautifulIdHere').timepicker();`

Comment: Thank you very much Tushar, I'm new to php and haven't done much web since graduating. Such a simple way to apply it to, be very useful in the future. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` keyword apply directly

```
<input type="text" onFocus="$(this).timepicker();;" value="13:23" class="form-control">
```

or you can assign `ID` for input tag

```
<input id='input1' type="text" onFocus="$('#input1').timepicker();;" value="13:23" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thanks Nagesh. I'm sure the 'this' keyword will prove useful further into development!